# Android Source code download using repo

Tags: android, git, repository, android-build

I am trying to build android from source since I need to customize something at a lower level. I download the entire source code to build from scratch using the command:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.4_r1
repo sync
```

The size is about 26gb. Only then did I realize that there was a simpler way to do this since a lot of modification were required and that was already done. What i had to do was :

```
repo init -u git://github.com/jamesonwilliams/platform_manifest.git -b android-4.4_r1.1
repo sync
```

Is there anyway I can use what I downloaded already . I tried issuing the above command in the same directory where I downloaded the original code form but it looks like it is starting from scratch.Any ideas?

Comment: Running `repo init` with the new URL followed by `repo sync` should be okay. I just tried it myself and it worked fine, although I didn't sync a full workspace, I just picked a couple of gits. Most of the Github manifest refers to the same gits as the original AOSP manifest so the old data should be reused (see the 'remote' attribute in .repo/manifest.xml and its default value set in the <default> tag near the top). Now, you _are_ running a sync so you'll likely be downloading _some_ updates from the upstream gits, but I'd be very surprised if you'd have to start from scratch.

Comment: Okay. I will try that out. Thanbks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

1. Do repo init in a new folder for android-4.4_r1.1
2. Copy .repo/projects folder from previous repo (android-4.4_r1) in to new repo's .repo/
3. Now run repo sync and it will be faster, it should only fetch delta